# Eclipse Crashing When Returning Null C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am having issues with my code. I want to return null when the array size is 0. However, when testing in Eclipse, it crashes. Any tips?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double* maximum(double* a, int size)
{
   if (size == 0)
   {
      return NULL;
   }
   double* m = a;
   double* p = a;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      if (*p > *m)
      {
         m = p;
      }
      p++;
   }
   return m;
}

int main()
{
   double data[] = {};
 double* max = maximum(data, 0);
   cout << *max << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot dereference a null pointer. Check that it is null before trying to access the pointed value. Also doesn't Eclipse provide some debug info instead of just crashing?

Comment: Dereferencing a NULL pointer is a no-no, it leads to undefined behavior. Don't do that! `cout << *max`

Comment: You're dereferencing a pointer returned from code *specifically* designed to return NULL in the case *you* invoked. Short of a dereference of a cast on an immediate `NULL` you would be hard-pressed to find a more direct invocation of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Hi @this.lau_ do you mean moving the if(size == 0) return NULL after the for loop? A little confused. Thanks!

Comment: @user3356901 it means `if (max) cout << *max << endl;`

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You can't have an array of size 0.

Comment: @chris it does compile (at least clang 3.4 eats it)

Comment: @MarkRansom can you give an example of how to do it correctly?

Comment: OP, your `maximum` function looks fine. The problem isn't there, nor is there anything wrong with returning `NULL`. Look at Neil's answer for the real problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Perhaps with `-pedantic`? I get this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7893f688c870bc9d

Comment: By the way, no need to reinvent `std::max_element`.

Comment: @user3356901 Fix what? Ie, what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

It is illegal to dereference a NULL pointer, which you do with `cout << *max << endl;`

Comment: Can you give an example of how to fix this?

Comment: To clarify even further, it seems like OP is stuck thinking the problem is with his `maximum_function` or that he returns `NULL`. The only problem is as you say. You can't dereference NULL.

Comment: @user3356901 if you're function can return NULL (and it can, because you've specifically coded it to do so) *you need to **check** for that on the caller side **before** dereferencing the resulting pointer*. The 5th comment in the list below your question is one way to do that.

Comment: @WhozCraig is Eclipse crashing because of the cout << *max << endl;

Comment: We all know that. You can not call "cout << *max << endl;" when max is null. You have check for NULL before calling the cout.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but @drescherjm could you give me an example? I don't understand why this is causing an issue or how to solve it.

Comment: if (max != NULL) cout << *max << endl;

Comment: @drescherjm I just tried this and my program doesn't crash. But it doesn't return NULL. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if (max != NULL) cout << *max << endl; else cout < "NULL" <<endl;

Comment: @drescherjm Doesn't this print "NULL"? I need it to return NULL. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Your function already returns NULL.

Comment: @drescherjm I want the program to return NULL if the array size is 0. I don't want to print "NULL" if the array size is 0.

Comment: return NULL to what? That part does not make sense.